# Run espresso tests after proguard

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-proguard

I am searching a way to run my espresso-tests after proguard was running - This should be a safety-net for a miss-configured proguard ( just had this after updating butterknife to 7.0 and forgot to update the proguard config )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are proguarding your APK using the standard mechanisms built into the Android Gradle build system (setting 'minifyEnabled true' for a particular buildType), you can test your 'proguarded' APK by setting the testBuildType as described [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basics-and-Configuration) and running your connectedAndroidTest task as normal.

For instance, if your 'release' buildType was the one configured to have proguard run against it, you would add the following to your gradle file:

```
android {
    testBuildType "release"
}
```

Comment: That sounds good ( I though testBuildType just then uses the right BuildConfig and so ) - if it even uses the signing/minify then this is awesome. Will try it out the weekend and accept the answer if it really works