# I want to run unit test and espresso test cases a specific build type

Tags: android, unit-testing, jenkins, gradle, android-espresso

I have a multiple falvoured and multiple build type project..having some espresso and unit test cases which are running successfully but to run them successfully i have mocked my api responses currently i change my build type manually in android studio to stagging and then run those tests. Now i am integrating my project with jenkins and in jenkins my tests failed becuase jenkins is running test cases on all build types.. So long story Short I want  my test cases to run only using staging build type..

Comment: I can't provide an answer without more information from you, but I think you can likely do what you want by following my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31819619/run-espresso-tests-after-proguard/32751358#32751358

Comment: @jdonmoyer i did that already but it didnt worked

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I answered with more details than my earlier comment.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Pleasure is mine.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [android test support flavors and build type variants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895869/android-test-support-flavors-and-build-type-variants/48895920), you can create `androidTest` and `test` folders for specific flavors. You can also extend this to build types. Gradle allows you to build tests for any specific combination of build-type and flavor.

Let's say you have two build types (`staging` and `debug`) and two flavors (`trial` and `full`). All of the following are valid folder names:

- `src/androidTestStaging` - tests to run for all flavors of `staging` build
- `src/testFull` - tests to run for all builds with `full` flavor
- `src/androidTestTrialDebug` - tests to run on only `trial` flavor of `debug` build
- `src/testFullStaging` - tests to run on only `full` flavor of `stagins` build

Each of these folders have the exact same directory structure as `androidTest` and `test` respectively. The tests in each folder will only be run against a build which is made from all of the specified build types and flavors.

Note that this can quickly explode into a lot of combinations. For example, if you have 3 build types and 2 flavor dimensions with 3 flavors each, you now have 27 different builds. Maintaining tests for each of these can be a nightmare, so you should still follow standard software engineering practices to write tests and helper classes and functions that can be reused as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks alot @Code-Apprentice .. I want to add one more thing here.. I have multiple flavours and multiple build types , so with the help of your answer on the comments  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895869/android-test-support-flavors-and-build-type-variants/48895920 .. I ended up making dir's like testFlavourARelease , testFlavourADebug,testFlavourAStagging (for unit test) and same would apply on espresso one's accordingly..

Comment: Now that is a perfect answer.. Hope it help someone else

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've tried your solution but sources for androidTest<some-build-type> are not recognized by android studio. If you'll be so kind and check my issue which is closely related to this problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112541/separate-androidtest-sourceset-for-different-buildtype-not-build-flavor

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you should correct your answer, it is not possible to create separate androidTest folders for every build-type. That's only possible for build `flavors` and `exclusively` for debug build-type(androidTestDebug)! Eg. if you have this build types: debug, release and integration you can't create androidTestIntegration directory for integration build-type instrumentation tests, the only one you can add is androidTestDebug. By executing `./gradlew sourceSets` you can see which sourceSets are allowed.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice unfortunately there is nothing about this issue in docs i came to that coclunsion by testing - am not sure if that's a bug or feature. You can try it in fresh project. The most important lead to me was `./gradlew sourceSets` which doesnt list `androidTestIntegration` sourceSet and on top of that it looks like android gradle plugin have dropped support for adding new custom sourceSets: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49601232/the-sourceset-commontest-is-not-recognized-by-the-android-gradle-plugin-perha#comment99352101_49601232` .

Answer (score 0):

Answered by [Code-apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440565/code-apprentice)
on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895869/android-test-support-flavors-and-build-type-variants/48895920?noredirect=1#comment87112384_48895920) question

If you want to run tests against a specific build type, you can specify it in the folder name: src/androidTestStaging or src/testStaging. You can combine build types and flavors to run specific tests: src/androidTestTrialStaging or src/testFullDebug.